# Bulksms sending with django

Tags: python, django, kannel, bulksms

I have a models like so

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Text(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

i want to be able to send bulk sms to some contacts

How do i go about linking this with kannel which is a free gateway

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.kannel.org/download/kannel-userguide-snapshot/userguide.html#AEN5058 :

> After you have configured Kannel to allow the sendsms service, you can send SMS messages via HTTP, e.g., using a WWW browser. The URL looks something like this:
>
> http://smsbox.host.name:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=foo&password=bar&to=0123456&text=Hello+world
>
> Thus, technically, you make an HTTP GET request. This means that all the information is stuffed into the URL. If you want to use this often via a browser, you probably want to make an HTML form for this.